# Regex.Match, startat and ^ (start of string)

Tags: c#, regex

Does some knows why the output of this code:

```
Regex re = new Regex("^bar", RegexOptions.Compiled);
string fooBarString = @"foo bar";

Match match1 = re.Match(fooBarString, 4);
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Match 1 sucess: {0}", match1.Success));

Match match2 = re.Match(fooBarString.Substring(4));
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Match 2 sucess: {0}", match2.Success));
```

is:

> Match 1 sucess: False
>
> Match 2 sucess: True

?

Expected behaviour is of course "True" and "True" (or else I really don't know what the "startat" parameter is supposed to be useful for).

The idea is that this regex matching (and there are lots of them) is called very often (several tousand per second) and we discovered that the substring operations are killing memory performance.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to MSDN

> If you want to restrict a match so
>   that it begins at a particular
>   character position in the string and
>   the regular expression engine does not
>   scan the remainder of the string for a
>   match, anchor the regular expression
>   with a \G (at the left for a
>   left-to-right pattern, or at the right
>   for a right-to-left pattern). This
>   restricts the match so it must start
>   exactly at startat.

The regexp is matched with the entire string, you will need to use \G instead of ^

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3583dcyh.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you're right - you're confused about the meaning of `^`. `^` means the very beginning of the line you're working with. `^bar` will only match lines that **begin** with "bar", which you've artificially done with `Substring` there. We might be able to help you if you explain what you're trying to do with it.

Incidentally, `Substring` should be *significantly* faster than most regex operations. I'd be surprised if that's what's killing your performance.

Comment: re performance: If `Substring` creates a new `String` object with a new copy of the underlying `Char`s (and I'm pretty sure it does), you'd be doing that *in addition to* the regex matching.  And the OP did in fact say the problem was with memory use, not speed, which makes `Substring` the prime suspect.  Fortunately, as @Maxime's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884922/regex-match-startat-and-start-of-string/5885087#5885087) shows, it isn't needed anyway.

Comment: @Alan - Yup, I made the mistake of thinking performance in terms of speed rather than memory (not saying `Substring` wouldn't be a speed hit, BTW, just that it was likely to be much less than the regex itself). @Maxime understood better what the poster was trying to do, so he gets my +1. Re the `Substring` method - That [does construct a new string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx), since strings are immutable in C#.

Comment: @JustinMorgan Actually the immutability is what would make it possible to not have to create a new string, it's possible the string could just point to the substring. The reason it doesn't do this has to do with garbage collection.